# Debezium Postgres some Update sql DML queries are logged as Delete + Insert Queries

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, debezium

I've noticed that some SQL Update queries in Postgres are logged as 2 DML queries (a delete query and a second insert query).

- Does anyone knows why Postgres is doing this (transforming an UPDATE to 2 DML statements DELETE+INSERT) ?
- Is there a way to force Postgres (or Debezium) to log this as an update statement ?

Could it be related to the fact that the query updates a field that is part of a foreign key and a constraint unique index ?

Regards

**More Info:**

The query is updating a table field that is part of a foreign key and another unique constraint

**Query:**

```
  UDDATE Table1 
  SET table2_id = :destinationTable2Id 
  WHERE 
  Table3_id IN (:table3Ids) AND 
  Table2_id = :sourceTable2Id AND 
  deleted_date is null
```

**Table:**

Table1(id, table2_id, table3_id, deleted_date, ...)

- with foreign keys constraints on table2_id, table3_id
- and unique constraints that include table2_id and table3_id and others

**Relationships:**

Table2 one-to-many --> Table1 <-- one-to-many Table3

Comment: Could you share your configuration of PostgreSQL and Debezium? UPDATE is logged as UPDATE when using logical replication.

Comment: Great question, I think it happens due to HOT optimizations: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-hot.html. Not sure exactly what's the fix there, but you may look at `tombstones delete` properties

Comment: @yahorbarkouski Why would HOT change an UPDATE statement into an DELETE and INSERT? That would definitely hit the indexes while the purpose of HOT is to avoid any write on the indexes.

Comment: My bad, I meant to say "due to missing", not "due to". My initial assumption is that if an update operation changes a column that is part of the index, it results in a delete operation for the old indexed value and an insert for the new one, but if it is appliable for hot, debezium may consider it as a single update instead. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Interesting note: I use Spring Boot JPA Repository with a native query for this .... and initially I did not understand why this update  query was always failing  IF I did not add the "@Transactional annotation".  Without the "@Transactional" annotation it would  Spring Boot(or postgres) would give me the following error message "Executing an update/delete query"